# Gmail python как отправлять электронные письма в ящик для промоакций

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, gmail

Есть скрипт отправки писем через Gmail:

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib

    gmail_user = user
    gmail_pwd = pwd
    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print 'successfully sent the mail'
    except:
        print "failed to send mail"
```

Все было бы хорошо, но он отправляет это все в Основной ящик. 
Поскольку я боюсь? что мою новостную рассылку потом будут отправлять в спам, я решил их сразу отправлять с меткой "Промоакции".
А вот как эту метку туда добавить, я не знаю.

Comment: Спамеры были бы рады такой возможности... Скорее всего никак. 99,9% что Гугл сам определяет категорию письма. И я бы искал такой вопрос: как составить содержимое рассылки, чтобы в Гугле ей присвоили тэг Promotions.

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev Смотри алекс, я через сайты россылки писем отправляю. И все письма доходят в коробку Промоакции. 
А если отправлять тоже самое через Питон скрипт , ну вот все тупо индентично. То письма доходят в основной ящик. И опять же у крупныих и мелких организациях все норм идет в промо. И они явно как-то это делают , вопрос как.

Comment: Вполне может быть, что есть некое коммерческое соглашение с Гуглом у таких почтовиков (организаций). Например, моя контора рассылает тонны писем (новости, счета) и я ни разу не видел, чтобы в гмыле они попадали в спец.категории. Надо будет изучить эту тему.

Comment: Беглое изучение англоязычного контента по этой теме (в том числе и стэковерфлоу - там есть полностью аналогичный вопрос) говорит следующее: smart labels это полностью автоматическая штука гугла. Повлиять на результаты его работы можно только в вебинтерфейсе своего аккаунта. Т.е. если хочешь другую категорию своему письму - поправь ее сам в интерфейсе и будет счастье.